# Question regarding Nodes pointing to null

Tags: java, null, nodes

The goal of my code is to delete every other node.

ex) 3,5,7,9.

I want the end goal to be 3,7.

If I want to delete “5” I could just set “3” to point to “7”. But if I want to delete “7”, can I just point it to null? Since 9 is already pointing to null?

Another example is For example, [3,9]
I want to get rid of 9, So can I do something like “front.next = front.next.next” even though there’s nothing there?

Answer (score 0):

For your first point, if you want to remove `7`, you'll need to make `5` (or whatever the node is before node `7`) to point to `9`.

For your second point:

```
front.next = front.next.next;
```

... will work fine.